# Best way to deploy new custom columns, contentype, and list instances?

Tags: content-type, custom-list, feature, site-column

I created in Visual Studio some new custom columns, these custom columns are inside my custom contenttype. I created a new list instance which is using this custom contenttype.

What is the best way to deploy these 3 (columns, contentype, list)? It is inportant they will be deployed in this order. First the columns, then the contenttype and as last the list. Do I need to add them to 1 feature or in 3 feature??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One feature containing all these three types i.e. columns, content type and list instance; should be enough.

Comment: what about the order? what if sharepoint try to install first the list or content type. It will throw an error that the columns are not exists!

Comment: You don't need to worry about the order, SharePoint will automagically take care of it.